# java.net.InetSocketAddress and java.net.SocketAddress Support IPv6?

Tags: java, ipv6, ipv4

Do java.net.InetSocketAddress and java.net.SocketAddress support IPv6?

Because the two classes that i have research and try it couldnt able me to view ipv6 connection it only able to view ipv4 connection anyone there have try and able to do the editing of the code?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.  `InetSocketAddress` takes an `InetAddress` and should accept either `Inet4Address` or `Inet6Address`.

Comment: ok then cux i try on netty-3.2.6.Final-dist the method of the java.net.SocketAddress could not able to find my Ipv6 addresses...

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer to your question, even though it may come too late to be of immediate use =).

I had the following lines of code attempt to connect to two different IP addresses:

```
// Defined port must be 13; that is NIST's default listening port.
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(currentIpAddress, 13);
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(socketAddress, nistServerTimeoutInMilliseconds);
```

The first address works fine : '206.246.122.250'

The second address throws a 'java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable' on the third line. That address is '2610:20:6F15:15::27'.

I thought at first that the problem was that IPv6 is not supported by InetSocketAddress in Java 1.7, but I found out that there are actually two classes that inherit from the InetAddress class in Java: Inet4Address and Inet6Address

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html

This explains why my code, when trying to construct an Inet4Address using an IPv6 format was failing, and it may explain your issue as well.

Hope this helps =)

P.S. InetAddress and InetSocketAddress aren't the same class, but by testing for the kind of IP address you're dealing with, there may be a way to get around the problem.